# Matlab Synchronize acquisition with Color/Depth of Kinect

Tags: matlab, synchronization, kinect

I'm having trouble to synchronize the color and depth image with Image acquisition ToolBox.

Currently, I'm just trying to log both streams into binary files without frame drop or losing the synchronization.

I don't try to render during my recording.

The code for the start button :

```
colorVid = videoinput('kinect',1); depthVid = videoinput('kinect',2);
colorVid.FramesPerTrigger = inf; depthVid.FramesPerTrigger = inf;
triggerconfig([colorVid depthVid],'manual');

iatconfigLogging(colorVid,'Video/Color.bin');
iatconfigLogging(depthVid,'Video/Depth.bin');

start([colorVid depthVid]);

pause(2); % this is to be sure both sensor are start before the trigger

trigger([colorVid depthVid]);
```

where the iatconfigureLogging() is from [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4792-custom-file-format-logging)

and the stop button just doing

```
stop([colorVid depthVid]);
```

Since the frames rate of the Kinect is 30FPS and we can't change this, I'm using FrameGrabInterval to emulate it.

But when I over like 5FPS, I can't log depth and color and keep the frames synchronized for more then 20-25 seconds. And except 1 FPS, the sync is over after 2-3 minutes and I'm looking for at least a 10-15 minutes acquisition.

I'm looking on something with like flushdata(obj,'triggers'); right now, but I don't figure it out how to keep the 30 FPS with the logging.

Thanks in advance for any one who will give something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot synchronize the streams by triggering because they are not synchronized in hardware. I tried it and the best I could come up with was timestamping each stream and throwing away frame pairs that were too far apart in time. I noticed the classic frequency offset effect whereby the streams move in and out of synch with inverse frequency of the difference between the periods of each. The obvious disadvantage of throwing away frames this is that you get a non-continuous stream. 
You can get timestamp information using

```
[data time] = getdata(vid,1);
```

Comment: Yep, I know, you can retrieve data,time and metadata for the skeleton part. Maybe I'll try it like you said. Check if at the same time stamps I have the same frame, else I really don't know what I gonna do. I'm trying to get 30 FPS because it camera spec, but my need is about 12-15 FPS, but this dont work either so... Did you have a code sample to log/get same time stamps frame ? If not it okay :)

Comment: The code I pasted above should give you the frame timestamps ... ?

Comment: It give the time the frame acquired and because when you start both stream, on sensor start before the other so frame don't have the same time start and automatically it hard to say when frame are sync. Manually, I can found some problem at different time (start or end), but Trying to code something to be robust right now and not that easy :P

Comment: Oh, yeah, I forgot about that. So what I did is I scrubbed through the first few frames and found the most well matched frames and defined the  zero timestamp for each stream at these pairs.

Comment: Did you have a code sample for that ? And How are you working when the number of total frame at the end are not similar ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the reason you need such perfectly synchronized streams?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38199/discussion-between-twerdster-and-alexandre-bizeau)